# SVN Server with single repo and no root path

Tags: windows, svn, collabnet

I have a strange SVN server configuration issue I cannot figure out.
A previous employee setup Collabnet svn server (version 1.6.9) on a windows server at work which we use for development. It's a great system, love using it.

We use a local LAN path for the repository with all our various folders, like this...

"svn://server1"

It has one repository called "repo".

I have recently installed a second SVN on another server (same version, same OS)

It has one repository called "main". In order to access it I have to use the svn path of ...

"svn://server2/main"

***So the question is...***. **does anyone know how we ended up with one server requiring to use a "repo name" after the server name (and does not work without it) and one server not requiring a "repo name" (and does not work with it)?**

The main reason for asking is I also need to setup additional repositories on the original server and do not want to affect the current configuration. I assume this is some level or option or configuration or a "default repo" setting or something, but I just can't seem to find where and how it was set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the  entry in your conf file.  If you have your svn information within a location tag, the location is the only way to access the repository.

Comment: Even though I have not confirmed it, the answer was in the config file (just didn't see it). It was "REALM=Main" in the one server and that option is missing completely from the other server (not "location" in my case). 
Thanks.